# Flutter How to remove the elevation of Navigation Rail

Tags: flutter, dart, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y80Al.png)

I'm using NaviationRail widget on Flutter Web.

And I want to remove the white line besides Naviagtion Rail.

I don't know the line is from elevation or border. But the fixing elevation doesn't work..

Sorry for my short English.

Comment: Can you show the code. That might be not on Navigation Rail. It might be another widget like a ```VerticalDivider```.

Comment: thanku,, your correct. The problem was VerticalDiver.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It is caused by elevation property of Navigation Rail. But you can't set elevation property of Navigation Rail to 0 or null by constructor.
but if you not set elevation property it is set to 0 by build. so, just remove 'elevation: 1' from your code.

If you need more help, please attach your code not image. :)